# Getting dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire, Reason: image not found

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, frameworks, carthage, rpath

I am working on creating custom framework and when I create normal swift class and generate .framework and use it in my another test project then it works fine. I am able to access all my implementations.

Problem starts here when I add **"Alamofire.framework"**(which I have generated through **carthage**) in my custom framework  and again try to use my custom framework in test project then getting this error.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire, Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, just open terminal and run command in your project directory:

```
pod install
```

Did solve my problem. Hopefully will work for you too.

Comment: it juts not the solution.